# How to make a bone follow location of two bones at same time?

Tags: bones

How can I make a bone follow the location of two other bones to always be between both of them?
I have 3 bones (2 feet and 1 torso), how can I make the torso bone always be between the 2 feet bones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this, by creating a [copy location constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/transform/copy_location.html#copy-location-constraint) for the bone, which has to be between the controlers.

> The Copy Location constraint forces its owner to have the same
>   location as its target.

Given are the three bones: footA, footB, torso (which has to be between footA and footB).

Make sure the torso bone **isn't connected** to another bone. It can have a parent though.

> Note that if you use such a constraint on a connected bone, it will
>   have no effect, as it is the parent’s tip which controls the position
>   of your owner bone’s root.

1. Add a **Copy Location Constraint** to *torso*. Set the Target to *footA*.
2. Add a **Copy Location Constraint** to *torso*. Set the Target to *footB*. Lower the *Influence* slider to 0.5 on this constraint.

The torso bone will move to *footA* with the first constraint. Then, with an Influence of 0.5, the *torso* bone will move halfway towards *footB*.

This can also be done for the rotation with *Copy Rotation Constraints*.